# Object not falling

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, nape

I created a space where there is gravity and two objects:

```haxe
var napeWorld:Space=new Space(new Vec2(0,500));
var ground:FlxNapeSprite = addBox(320, 480, 640, 20, BodyType.STATIC, FlxColor.BLUE);
var hero=addBox(320,60,20,20,BodyType.DYNAMIC, FlxColor.RED);
```

Here is my `addBox()` function:

```haxe
private function addBox(x:Float, y:Float, w:Float, h:Float,bodyType:BodyType, color:Int):FlxNapeSprite {
    var sprite:FlxNapeSprite = new FlxNapeSprite(x, y);
    sprite.makeGraphic(Math.ceil(w), Math.ceil(h), color);
    sprite.body.type = bodyType;
    sprite.body.space = napeWorld;
    //sprite.createRectangularBody(w, h, bodyType);
    sprite.setBodyMaterial();
    add(sprite);
    return sprite;
}
```

I call step in my `update()` method:

```haxe
override public function update():Void
{
    super.update();
    napeWorld.step(1/30);
}
```

I don't understand why my dynamic shape doesn't fall on the ground...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are setting it to be a static body with `BodyType.STATIC`.

You need `BodyType.DYNAMIC` to make things move by themselves.